# linq select items where property of items in list not in properties of items in another list

Tags: linq, join, except

I have two lists of 2 different types of classes.  I want to select all of the items in the first list that have a property (we'll call it name) that do not have coresponding objects with same name in another list.

For example if I have a list of Age items (joe, 4), (marry,5), (ed,2)

and another list of relation items (joe,father), (ed,brother)

I want to end up with a resulting list of (marry,5)

I was not sure if "except" was somehow used here.

Comment: Any code effort we can hook in to? Preparing some sample data would help.

Answer (score 0):

Given two arrays (I'm using anonymous types here, but it's the same deal with proper classes) of different types, you're going to need to extract the excepted 'key' first. In this case the 'key' is the `Name` property.

```
//Setup
var ageItems = new [] { new {Name = "Joe", Age=4}, new {Name = "Marry", Age=5}, new {Name="Ed", Age=2} };
var relationItems = new [] { new {Name="Joe", Rel = "Father"}, new {Name="Ed", Rel="Brother"} };

//Get the names
var exceptedNames = ageItems.Select (a => a.Name).Except(relationItems.Select (r => r.Name));

//At this point, we have an `IEnumerable` containing 'Marry', we need to get the instances
var exceptedItems = ageItems.Where(a => exceptedNames.Contains(a.Name));
```

Of course, being LINQ, you can whack it all into one call:

```
var exceptedItems = ageItems.Where (a => ageItems.Select (b => b.Name).Except(relationItems.Select (r => r.Name)).Contains(a.Name));
```

You can't use the `.Except` overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer` instance as your classes differ, and `IEqualityComparer` can only compare two items of the same type, hence we have to generalise and pull out the same fields.